# What nix function can I use to get the file extension?

Tags: nix

Often when building haskell projects I run into an error of the cabal file being present when using hpack instead.

```
niobiumcoconut.cabal was generated with a newer version of hpack, please upgrade and try again.
```

So I thought, hey a a solution would be to exclude the cabal file to the derivation. I've found the `builtins.filterSource` function. However I'm not sure how to get the file extension from a file with nix (so I can exclude `*.cabal` files.)

Does such a function exist? Where is it defined? And how do I use it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're looking for the [hasSuffix](https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/blob/8272eff97ae2a874800ba7bbe730e0924cbaca1c/lib/strings.nix#L198) function.

Answer (score 1):

To remove the particular file based on the extension:

```
src = pkgs.lib.cleanSourceWith {
    filter = name: type:
      !(pkgs.lib.hasSuffix ".example" name)
    ;
    src = ./.;
  };
```

This answer was provided by "Andika Demas Riyandi" from functionalprogramming.slack.com